# Make an effective projection of matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

To best explain my problem, I will take the following example:

Consider the following matrix :

`A = {{1, 2, 3, 4, ""}, {"", 2, 3, 4, ""}, {"", "", 3, 4, ""}, {"", "", "", 4, 5}}`

I designed the following two algorithms :

```
ProjVt[x_, y_, pat_] :=
     Block[
                {X = x, Y = y, Grid11, Grid21, Resvf1},

                Grid11 = PosGrid[X, pat];

                Grid21 = ConstantArray["", 10000];

                Table[
                      Table[
                            Grid21[[ Grid11[[i, j]] ]] = X[[i, Grid11[[i, j]] [[1]]  ]],
                            {j, 1, Length[Grid11[[i]]], 1}
                           ],
                            {i, 1, Length[X], 1}
                    ];

                 Resvf1 =  Grid21[[1 ;; Length[Y]]]

            ];
```

and

```
ProjHt[x_, y_, pat_] :=
Block[
               {X = x, Y = y, Grid12, Grid22, Resvf2},

                Grid12 = PosGrid[X, pat];

                Grid22 = ConstantArray["", 10000];

                Table[
                       Grid22[[i]] = X[[ i , Grid12[[i, 1, 1]] ;; Grid12[[i, -1, 1]] ]],
                       {i, 1, Length[X], 1}
                     ];

                Resvf2 = DeleteCases[Grid22, ""]

            ];
```

The results provided by `ProjVt` and `ProjHt` in the case of matrix `A` are :

> ```
> Resvf1 = {1,2,3,4,5}
> Resvf2 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}
> ```

Best known optimization :

---

```
ProjHt[X_]:= Map[Select[#, NumberQ] &, X]

ProjVt[X_]:=
Block[
      {step1, Res},
       step1 = Tranpose[x];
       Res = ProjHt[step1][[All,1]]
     ]
```

.

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates@Cases[A, _?NumberQ, {2}]` and as you have already written: `Map[Select[#, NumberQ] &, A]`?

Comment: Hey Doedalos. Note that I fixed `Tr(X)` to `Tr[X]`. Please try making code blocks using the shortcut control/command + k, rather than using ` (backtick) for large code blocks.

Comment: @Doedalos Well, replace `A` with `X`? :) And then `ProjVtalt1[A]` :) So you would need `ProjVtalt1[mat_]:=DeleteDuplicates[Cases[mat,_?NumberQ,{2}]]`

Comment: @Doedalos If you wish you can answer your own question :) That would be great :)

Comment: @Doedalos Please answer your own question with the informations provided in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A /. "" -> Sequence[]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}

Answer (score 0):

Best known optimization :

```
A = {{1, 2, 3, 4, ""}, {"", 2, 3, 4, ""}, {"", "", 3, 4, ""}, {"", "","", 4, 5}}

ProjHt[X_]:= Map[Select[#, NumberQ] &, X]

ProjVt[X_]:=
Block[
      {step1, Res},
       step1 = Transpose[x];
       Res = ProjHt[step1][[All,1]]
     ]

ProjHt[A]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}
> ```